# Webpack: Converting JS to SASS and CSS

Tags: webpack, sass, webpack-4, webpack-style-loader, sass-loader

My goal is to create a SASS and CSS file from the Javascript file that contains all of my themes and colors from which I iterate.

I have a `themes.js` file which contains two objects that hold all of my color patterns: `colorPalette` and `themes`. I am importing those objects into my entry point (`./src/index.js`). The entry point uses JS to iterate through all of the palettes and themes to create a large SASS string. Using the HtmlWebpack plugin, I can print this to the DOM. However, my main goal is to create a SASS file with this output string. I've used the sass, style, and css loaders as well as the `miniCssExtract` and `textExtract` plugins to try to capture this string as a SASS file. I've played around with the config quite a bit (adding multiple plugins, remove them all, etc.), but below is my latest iteration:

```
var config = { 
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['style-loader','css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      }
    ]
  }
}

var clientConfig = ({ mode, presets } = { mode: "production", presets: [] }) => {
  return webpackMerge(
    {
      mode,
      plugins: [ new HtmlWebpackPlugin()]
    },
    modeConfig(mode),
    presetConfig({ mode, presets }),
  Object.assign({}, config, {
    name:"main",
    entry: "./src/index",
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname +'dist'),
      filename: "bundle.js"
    }
    })
  )
}

module.exports = [clientConfig]
```

I understand that the file that webpack outputs is the runtime file which is an array of multiple modules that get wrapped up but I don't understand how to (or if I should) use that to generate my SASS file. I feel like I'm a little bit off on how to approach webpack so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what each of those plugins do. The minicss plugin is supposed to pull your imported CSS string from within the JS and make it its own file. To my knowledge, It doesn't pull the CSS from the DOM itself. The style-loader injects styles into the DOM, but before that you have to transpile SASS to CSS with the sass-loader, and resolve imports with the css-loader. I assume what you're trying to do is make a sort of _sass-variables_ file from your JS object, right? In that case, why not try something like [style-dictionary](https://amzn.github.io/style-dictionary/#/)?

Comment: Style dcitionary is what I needed. thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

You can reference to my code [here](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/webpack.config.js)

```
module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            minimize: true,
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Then just import the file in your js like this

```
import "style.scss";
```